# What does 'to lose countenance, with a good countenance' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I know countenance means appearance, behavior, and composure.  What does the phrase 'to lose countenance, with a good countenance' mean?

Comment: It means "keeping your composure even though you've lost face" (i.e. not betraying your shame with your face or facial expression). Stiff upper lip and all that. It's contrasting the literal and metaphorical meanings of *countenance* / *face*.

Comment: Can you put it into an answer?

Comment: If you don't mind that I offer no authorities to back it up, I will.

Comment: To suffer indignities with grace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED: s.v. ***countenance*** n.1

> **6.a.** ‘Calmness of look, composure of face’; ‘confidence of mien’ (Johnson); esp. in phr. ***to lose countenance, with a good countenance.***

Essentially, then, “to lose one’s cool,” and “while maintaining composure,” respectively, and in both cases as expressed in one’s face.